# Getting 'The instance of entity type 'X'' Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just want to ask why i am getting this error when I am trying to insert multiple data in 2 tables. Thank you for your answer in advanced.

[This the the error I am getting in exception handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4lek.png)

This is my Source Code

```
public void CreateCollection(IEnumerable<CollectionViewModel> p , IEnumerable<Claim> user)
        {          
            var userId = Convert.ToUInt32(user.Single(logon => logon.Type == CustomClaimTypes.UserId).Value);
            /*Create access table for insert*/

            var modules = p.Select(collection => new Accountcollection
            {
                AccountId = userId,
                Amount = collection.Amount,
                CashSource = collection.CashSource,
                CollectionDate = collection.CollectionDate,
                CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
            }).ToList();

            _context.Accountcollection.AddRange(modules);            

            var calendar_event = p.Select(collection => new Accountcalendarevents
            {
                AccountId = userId,
                Subject = collection.CashSource,
                Description = collection.CashSource,
                Start = collection.CollectionDate,
                End = collection.CollectionDate,
                ThemeColor = "blue",
                Isfullday = true,
                Status = "1",
                CreatedBy = userId,
                CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedBy = userId,
                UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now
            }).ToList();

            _context.Accountcalendarevents.AddRange(calendar_event);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

this is my account calendar events entity

```
public class Accountcalendarevents
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public string ThemeColor { get; set; }
        public bool Isfullday { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
        public long UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDatetime { get; set; }

    }
```

and my account collection entity

```
public long Id { get; set; }
        public long AccountId { get; set; }
        public double? Amount { get; set; }
        public string CashSource { get; set; }
        public DateTime CollectionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDatetime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
        public Accountcalendarevents Accountcalendarevents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context to your issue. Code, logic, the more the better. My guess is you are trying to add a detached entity to your context.

Comment: I have already added mr @Dimitri

Comment: Thank you. Can you add your Accountcollection entity please?

Comment: I have already add it in my question thank you

Comment: Try use of .AsNoTracking() method.

Comment: Where do i need to add the .AsNoTracking() method? @Hardik

Comment: On DbSet @PaulVincentDoroyan `dbContext.<Table>.AsNoTracking()` and also you need to write additional code for AddRange()

Comment: Didn't get where do i need to punt asnotracking in my codes. @Hardik

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
_context.Accountcollection.AddRange(modules);
_context.SaveChanges();

.
.
.
_context.Accountcalendarevents.AddRange(calendar_event);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @PaulVincentDoroyan is AccountId primary key for both table ?

Comment: no, they have both different primary key. accountid is a foreign key of account collection from accountcalendarevents

Comment: Do you have the [Key] attribute defined?

Comment: Ive added my entites used in my question.

Comment: Can you try adding the [Key] attribute to the public long Id { get; set; } for both your entities please?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what it is you want to achieve specifically? Are there other Entities involved as well? Thank you

Comment: Can you try to remove the  public long AccountId { get; set; } from your Accountcalendarevents Entity and see if that resolves your issue?

Comment: Removing accoundId from accountcalendarevents solved my problem. But I need a foregin key to insert with that.