# Problem Insterting Multiple data on 2 tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am having problem on inserting multiple data in two tables. 
Here is my code

**Context Class**

```
var userId = Convert.ToUInt32(user.Single(logon => logon.Type == CustomClaimTypes.UserId).Value);
            /*Create access table for insert*/

            var modules = p.Select(collection => new Accountcollection
            {
                AccountId = userId,
                Amount = collection.Amount,
                CashSource = collection.CashSource,
                CollectionDate = collection.CollectionDate,
                CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
            }).ToList();

            _context.Accountcollection.AddRange(modules);

            var calendar_event = p.Select(collection => new Accountcalendarevents
            {
                AccountId = userId,
                Subject = collection.CashSource,
                Description = collection.CashSource,
                Start = collection.CollectionDate,
                End = collection.CollectionDate,
                ThemeColor = "blue",
                Isfullday = true,
                Status = "1",
                CreatedBy = userId,
                CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedBy = userId,
                UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now
            }).ToList();

            _context.Accountcalendarevents.AddRange(calendar_event);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

**This is my collection model**

```
public partial class Accountcollection
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long AccountId { get; set; }
        public double? Amount { get; set; }
        public string CashSource { get; set; }
        public DateTime CollectionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDatetime { get; set; }

        //public Accountcalendarevents Accountcalendarevents { get; set; }

        public virtual Accountmaster Account { get; set; }

    }
```

**And this is my Caldendar Manager Events Model**

```
public class Accountcalendarevents
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }   

        public long AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public string ThemeColor { get; set; }
        public bool Isfullday { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
        public long UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDatetime { get; set; }

    }
```

The problem is when I insert only 1 data in works fine but if I try to insert 2 or more, i am getting this kind of exception
[Exception i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtVC8.png)

But, when I commented

```
var calendar_event = p.Select(collection => new Accountcalendarevents
            {
                //AccountId = userId, <-- when I comment this line
                Subject = collection.CashSource,
                Description = collection.CashSource,
                Start = collection.CollectionDate,
                End = collection.CollectionDate,
                ThemeColor = "blue",
                Isfullday = true,
                Status = "1",
                CreatedBy = userId,
                CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedBy = userId,
                UpdatedDatetime = DateTime.Now
            }).ToList();
```

it works properly on multiple data insertion.

Hope you helped me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `AsNoTracking()` after `p`: `p.AsNoTracking().Select(...)`. The problem seem occurred from EF's entity tracking mechanism.

Comment: I try it earlier but its saids that `IEnumerable<CollectionViewModel> does not contain a definition for AsNoTracking` @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: @PaulVincentDoroyan What is `p` in the `p.Select(..`?

Comment: Both `p` on it @TanvirArjel

Comment: @PaulVincentDoroyan This is strange! `AccountId` is not primary key but still complaining!

Comment: Yeah :( Im trying to fix it for almost a week. @TanvirArjel

Comment: Duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236492/getting-the-instance-of-entity-type-x-exception/55236817#comment97215695_55236817

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 'The instance of entity type 'X'' Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236492/getting-the-instance-of-entity-type-x-exception)